Ubuntu 24.04 stopped detecting external monitors over Thunderbolt connection
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 on Lenovo Yoga Pro 7, it all worked fine.
About a week ago the connecting external screens using Thunderbolt connection stopped working, the rest of things are working, like charging, Mouse and keyboard.
But, the external display is not recognized.
Connecting it directly to the HDMI socket is working.

If that problem started after a kernel upgrade, reboot into grub and select the previous kernel to load.

Which kernel version are you using? Which Thunderbolt dock are you using? Which monitors are you using?  Is your Thunderbolt dock patched to its latest version of its firmware?  Does it work on Windows?

It ended up that it was a board issue, and Lenovo service had to replace the board.
The fact that some of the functionality worked, like USB and charging and some didn't like Display and LAN on both ports indicated for their service that it's a board issue.

This is my workaround but YMMV:
when waking up from sleep, my Dell XPS laptop with Ubuntu 22 fails to activate
my external LG monitor connected via (usb-c to displayport cable / thunderbolt?)
My workaround is to switch to console (CTRL-ALT-F3), waiting a few seconds for the text-only login prompt to appear also on the external monitor, and finally to switch back to the GUI with CTRL-ALT-F2

tried but no effect

I'm a new contributor so I don't have the ability to comment yet; you don't list what drivers you have, but have you tried updating the graphic drivers? You could also try force restarting the display driver with the below command:
sudo systemctl restart gdm

Make sure that you save your work before running this, it will log out for you.

Had a slightly different problem. After performing a routine update to ubuntu 24.04 my mouse and keyboard died shortly after logging on through the GUI. Solution was to NOT perform GUI login, but use Ctrl-Alt-F3, and login to command prompt; then perform a "sudo apt update" followed by "sudo apt upgrade". Several packages were updated. I logged out of the command line and used Ctrl-Alt-F1 to switch back to GUI and login. All worked fine.
